# Avoid for loop when loop has an increment

Tags: r, for-loop, lapply

In R, I try systematically to avoid "for" loops and use `lapply()` family instead.
But how to do so when an iteration contains an increment step ?

For example : is it possible to obtain the same result as below with a `lapply` approach ?

```r
a <- c()
b <- c()
set.seed(1L) # required for reproducible data
for (i in 1:10){
  a <- c(a, sample(c(0,1), 1))
  b <- c(b, (paste(a, collapse = "-")))
}
data.frame(a, b)


> data.frame(a, b)
>    a                   b
> 1  0                   0
> 2  1                 0-1
> 3  0               0-1-0
> 4  0             0-1-0-0
> 5  1           0-1-0-0-1
> 6  0         0-1-0-0-1-0
> 7  0       0-1-0-0-1-0-0
> 8  0     0-1-0-0-1-0-0-0
> 9  1   0-1-0-0-1-0-0-0-1
> 10 1 0-1-0-0-1-0-0-0-1-1
```

---

**EDIT**
My question was very badly redacted. The below new example is much more illustrative : is it anyway to use `lapply` family if each iteration is calculated from the previous one ?

```r
a <- c()
b <- c()
for (i in 1:10){
  a <- c(a, sample(c(0,1), 1))
  b <- c(b, (paste(a, collapse = "-")))
}
data.frame(a, b)

> data.frame(a, b)
   a                   b
1  0                   0
2  1                 0-1
3  0               0-1-0
4  1             0-1-0-1
5  1           0-1-0-1-1
6  1         0-1-0-1-1-1
7  1       0-1-0-1-1-1-1
8  0     0-1-0-1-1-1-1-0
9  1   0-1-0-1-1-1-1-0-1
10 1 0-1-0-1-1-1-1-0-1-1
```

Answer (score 4):

For the sake of completeness, there is also the `accumulate()` function from the `purrr` package.

So, building on the answers of [Sotos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60110357/3817004) and [ThomasIsCoding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60110510/3817004):

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:10)
df$b <- purrr::accumulate(df$a, paste, sep = "-")
df
```

> ```
>     a                    b
> 1   1                    1
> 2   2                  1-2
> 3   3                1-2-3
> 4   4              1-2-3-4
> 5   5            1-2-3-4-5
> 6   6          1-2-3-4-5-6
> 7   7        1-2-3-4-5-6-7
> 8   8      1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8
> 9   9    1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9
> 10 10 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10
> ```

The difference to `Reduce()` is

- that `accumulate()` is a function verb on its own (no additional parameter `accumulate = TRUE` required)
- and that additional arguments like `sep = "-"` can be passed on to the mapped function which may help to avoid the creation of an anonymous function.

#### EDIT

If I understand correctly OP's edit of the question, the OP is asking if a `for` loop which computes a result iteratively can be replaced by `lapply()`.

This is difficult to answer for me. Here are some thoughts and observations:

**First**, `accumulate()` still will work:

```
set.seed(1L) # required for reproducible data
df <- data.frame(a = sample(0:1, 10L, TRUE))
df$b <- purrr::accumulate(df$a, paste, sep = "-")
df
```

> ```
>    a                   b
> 1  0                   0
> 2  1                 0-1
> 3  0               0-1-0
> 4  0             0-1-0-0
> 5  1           0-1-0-0-1
> 6  0         0-1-0-0-1-0
> 7  0       0-1-0-0-1-0-0
> 8  0     0-1-0-0-1-0-0-0
> 9  1   0-1-0-0-1-0-0-0-1
> 10 1 0-1-0-0-1-0-0-0-1-1
> ```

This is possible because the computation of `a` can be pulled out off the loop as it does not depend on `b`.

IMHO, `accumulate()` and `Reduce()` do what the OP is looking for but is not called `lapply()`: They take the result of the previous iteration and combine it with the actual value, for instance

```
Reduce(`+`, 1:3)
```

returns the sum of 1, 2, and 3 by iteratively computing `(((0 + 1) + 2) + 3)`. This can be visualised by using the `accumulate` parameter

```
Reduce(`+`, 1:3, accumulate = TRUE)
```

> ```
> [1] 1 3 6
> ```

**Second**, there is a major difference between a `for` loop and functions of the `lapply()` family: `lapply(X, FUN, ...)` requires a function `FUN` to be called on each element of `X`. So, scoping rules for functions apply.

When we transplant the body of the loop into an anonymous function within `lapply()`

```
a <- c()
b <- c()
set.seed(1L) # required for reproducible data
lapply(1:10, function(i) {
  a <- c(a, sample(c(0,1), 1))
  b <- c(b, (paste(a, collapse = "-")))
})
```

we get

> ```
> [[1]]
> [1] "0"
>
> [[2]]
> [1] "1"
>
> [[3]]
> [1] "0"
>
> [[4]]
> [1] "0"
>
> [[5]]
> [1] "1"
>
> [[6]]
> [1] "0"
>
> [[7]]
> [1] "0"
>
> [[8]]
> [1] "0"
>
> [[9]]
> [1] "1"
>
> [[10]]
> [1] "1"
> ```

```
data.frame(a, b)
```

> ```
> data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows    data.frame(a, b)
> ```

Due to the scoping rules, `a` and `b` *inside* the function are considered as local to the function. No reference is made to `a` and `b` defined *outside* of the function.

This can be fixed by *global assignment* using the *global assignment operator* `<<-`:

```
a <- c()
b <- c()
set.seed(1L) # required for reproducible data
lapply(1:10, function(i) {
  a <<- c(a, sample(c(0,1), 1))
  b <<- c(b, (paste(a, collapse = "-")))
})
data.frame(a, b)
```

> ```
>    a                   b
> 1  0                   0
> 2  1                 0-1
> 3  0               0-1-0
> 4  0             0-1-0-0
> 5  1           0-1-0-0-1
> 6  0         0-1-0-0-1-0
> 7  0       0-1-0-0-1-0-0
> 8  0     0-1-0-0-1-0-0-0
> 9  1   0-1-0-0-1-0-0-0-1
> 10 1 0-1-0-0-1-0-0-0-1-1
> ```

However, `global assignment` is considered bad programming practice and should be avoided, see, e.g., the *6th Circle of [Patrick Burns' The R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf)* and many questions on SO.

**Third**, the way the loop is written grows vectors in the loop. This also is considered bad practice as it requires to copy the data over and over again which may slow down tremendously with increasing size. See, e.g., the *2nd Circle of [Patrick Burns' The R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf)*.

However, the original code

```
a <- c()
b <- c()
set.seed(1L) # required for reproducible data
for (i in 1:10) {
  a <- c(a, sample(c(0,1), 1))
  b <- c(b, (paste(a, collapse = "-")))
}
data.frame(a, b)
```

can be re-written as

```
a <- integer(10)
b <- character(10)
set.seed(1L) # required for reproducible data
for (i in seq_along(a)) {
  a[i] <- sample(c(0,1), 1)
  b[i] <- if (i == 1L) a[1] else paste(b[i-1], a[i], sep = "-")
}
data.frame(a, b)
```

Here, vectors are pre-allocated with the required size to hold the result. Elements to update are identified by subscripting.

Calculation of `b[i]` still depends only the value of the previous iteration `b[i-1]` and the actual value `a[i]` as requested by the OP.

Comment: Really elegant indeed. I did not know this.
In terms of performance, is it comparable to `lapply` ? I will test this.

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to use `Reduce` with `accumulate = TRUE`, i.e.

```
df$new <- do.call(rbind, Reduce(paste, split(df, seq(nrow(df))), accumulate = TRUE))
```

which gives,

> ```
>     a                  new
> 1   1                    1
> 2   2                  1 2
> 3   3                1 2 3
> 4   4              1 2 3 4
> 5   5            1 2 3 4 5
> 6   6          1 2 3 4 5 6
> 7   7        1 2 3 4 5 6 7
> 8   8      1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
> 9   9    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
> 10 10 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sapply` (`lapply` would work too but it returns a list) and iterate over every value of `a` in `df` and create a sequence and `paste` the value together.

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:10)
df$b <- sapply(df$a, function(x) paste(seq(x), collapse = "-"))
df

#    a                    b
#1   1                    1
#2   2                  1-2
#3   3                1-2-3
#4   4              1-2-3-4
#5   5            1-2-3-4-5
#6   6          1-2-3-4-5-6
#7   7        1-2-3-4-5-6-7
#8   8      1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8
#9   9    1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9
#10 10 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10
```

---

If there could be non-numerical values in data on which we can not use `seq` like

```
df <- data.frame(a =letters[1:10])
```

In those case, we can use

```
df$b <- sapply(seq_along(df$a), function(x) paste(df$a[seq_len(x)], collapse = "-"))
df

#   a                   b
#1  a                   a
#2  b                 a-b
#3  c               a-b-c
#4  d             a-b-c-d
#5  e           a-b-c-d-e
#6  f         a-b-c-d-e-f
#7  g       a-b-c-d-e-f-g
#8  h     a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h
#9  i   a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h-i
#10 j a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h-i-j
```

Comment: With my use case formally, this is a good answer. But, your code is possible because you know *in advance* what will be the value of b. You know that if df[4,"a"] = 4, then df[4, "b"] will be 1-2-3-4.
But what if you have to know the value of df[3, "b"] to calculate df[4, "b"] ? This was the purpose of my question.

Comment: @Jrm_FRL If every value is dependent on the previous value I don't think `lapply` would work in that case. You could use `Reduce` or `accumulate` solution in such case.

Comment: I think you are right. I have edited my question anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of using `Reduce`, different to the approach by [@Sotos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60110357/12158757)

```
df$b <- Reduce(function(...) paste(...,sep = "-"), df$a, accumulate = T)
```

such that

```
> df
    a                    b
1   1                    1
2   2                  1-2
3   3                1-2-3
4   4              1-2-3-4
5   5            1-2-3-4-5
6   6          1-2-3-4-5-6
7   7        1-2-3-4-5-6-7
8   8      1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8
9   9    1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9
10 10 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10
```